# How to have Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-design-library

I'm looking to have the same design for Pre-Lollipop devices.

In my application I'm using a switch button which is looking like this on Lollipop devices :

[image]

and on Pre-Lollipop devices. it's looking like this :

[image]

So how can I do that I have two styles folders :

[image]

my Styles xml looks like :

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For switch you need to use the new android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`SwitchCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) class instead of `Switch` to provide backwards compatibility.